# What is this plane seen in Mobile, Alabama?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, jet, b-52

This was taken at the USS Alabama in Mobile, Alabama. It is probably a US Navy aircraft.

[image: This is probably a US Navy Aircraft]

Comment: It's a B-52, not sure what variant.

Comment: Was type aircraft NOT on the information plaque you can see on the left side of the photo?!

Comment: @Michael Hall-He may not have been at the museum but looking at a picture taken there.

Answer (score 17):

[image]
([Source](https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7605/27273400154_3fa64e11bd_b.jpg))

### [B-52D Stratofortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) "Calamity Jane".

It is a long-range, subsonic, strategic bomber operated by the US Air Force (not the Navy) since 1955.

> The aircraft you see here was amoung 170 B-52Ds manufactured by Boeing Airplane Company, and was equipped exclusively for long-range bombing missions. "Calamity Jane", as she is called, has been demilitarized, but remains in the high camouflage used during Vietnam operations. ([Source](http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WM5GN3_B_52D_Stratofortress_Calamity_Jane_Mobile_Alabama))

[image]

Comment: To answer the OP's other question (or assumption), the aircraft was operated by the US Air Force, not the US Navy.

Comment: The most important question: Why is the skin so wrinkled? The answer: If you were born in 1955, your skin would be wrinkly by now, too.

Answer (score 5):

That is a USAF B-52D. These were used extensively in Vietnam, and were retired after. The 2 models that remained in operation after 1983, when the last D-model was retired, were the G and H models. The G models were retired in 1991, leaving only H models still in active service. They are expected to last into the 2050s. The last B-52 built was in 1962, which means that the aircraft will have nearly a century of service. I am honored that I was assigned as a B-52G Crew Chief, 1989-1995

Answer (score 0):

It is a B-52 called "Calamity Jane". Not a navy aircraft because there is no way they could fit that behemoth of a plane on an aircraft carrier.

Comment: Welcome to [aviation.se]! Does this post really add any value beyond the accepted answer?